# Adding events to fullCalendar, agenda view

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm trying to create a course scheduling website. Ideally, users could type a course's name into the text box, then press "Add", and it would appear on October 27, at 3:30pm. This is not happening.

```
    $('#add-course-name').click(function() {
        var myEvent = {
            id:100,
            title: $('#course-name-number').val(),

            start: new Date(2011, 10, 27, 15, 30),
            end: new Date(2011, 10, 27, 18, 30),
            allDay: false,
        }
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', myEvent, true);
    });
```

It's correctly creating "myEvent", and I'm able to initialize the calendar with static events. Any help in troubleshooting this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Months are 0 based. If you want it to render in October, then you should be using

```
new Date(2011, 9, 27, 15, 30),
```

With your current code, the event is probably rendering on November 27th instead.